# Xamarin Forms Project: "Method 'Plugin.Share.Abstractions.IShare.OpenBrowser' not found"

Tags: xamarin

I added in a Xamarin Forms project the "Plugin.Share" plugin and tried to use the OpenBrowser method.

Thus:
CrossShare.Current.OpenBrowser ("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=" + youtubeItem.VideoId, null);

But I'm getting the following error in response:

***"Method 'Plugin.Share.Abstractions.IShare.OpenBrowser' not found"***.

Can anyone tell you what the problem is?

Thank you.

Comment: I solved the problem by removing the updated version of "Plugin.Share" (5.0.0) and installing version 4.0.2.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the linker removing the method.

Try editing the iOS or Android project options and setting "Linker Behavior" to "Don't Link".

Comment: I solved the problem by removing the updated version of "Plugin.Share" (5.0.0) and installing version 4.0.2.

Answer (score 0):

It was just a problem with the version. The implementation must have been modified.

I solved the problem by removing the updated version of "Plugin.Share" (5.0.0) and installing version 4.0.2.